# Two GridView in Same Location

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two GridViews namely GridView1  and GridView2 .They are  in same Location and I declare a boolean variable namely flag. I want to do that when flag=false  ,  GridView1 is visible and GridView2 is invisible. When flag=true , GridView2 is visible and GridView1 is invisible. Here is my code.

```
private bool flag=false;  
if(flag==false)  
{  
    GridView1.Visible=true;  
    GridView2.Visible=false;  
    flag=true;  
}  
else  
{
    GridView2.Visible=true; 
    GridView1.Visible=false;
    flag=false;  
}
```

In RunTime,
Though GridView2 become invisible, the space of it is appeared under GridView1. How could I do to show a Grid at one time .

With Regrads,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put both **GridView** in Div.

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
</div>


<div id="div2" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

At code side

```
if(flag==false)  
{  
    div1.Visible=true;  
    div2.Visible=false;  
    flag=true;  
}  
else  
{
    div2.Visible=true; 
    div1.Visible=false;
    flag=false;  
}
```

Comment: thanks for your attention and answer. I am OK with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Store flag value in ViewState.

```
        if (ViewState["flag"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["flag"] = false;
        }

        bool flag = (bool)ViewState["flag"];

        GridView1.Visible = flag;
        GridView2.Visible = !flag;
        ViewState["flag"] = !flag;
```

Comment: The OP's problem is that the space for the non-visible GridView was still there, even though the GridView was not visible.  Your code snippet doesn't address that problem.